# Bitbucket login password not working for authentication while pushing changes on git remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

A day ago I was able to push on git without entering any password, but now getting prompt to enter a possword, I am entering my bitbucket login password but it is not working and I am getting below message:

> git push origin issue/abc-issue
> remote: Invalid credentials
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/company-name/repo-name.git/'

I am not able to figure out which password I need to enter here, I looked for solution on internet but none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking for solution on various bitbucket Atlassian blogs/forums.
I understood that I need to match my local git username with that of my bitbucket profile username.

Refernce: [Authentication Error - "remote: Invalid username or password"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/authentication-error-remote-invalid-username-or-password-942864127.html)

I updated git username

> git config --global user.name "myusername"

Then I went to bitbucket personal settings > app passwords

and

created new password by selecting all write permissions.

> Note: the password created is different from your account login
> password and it is a random string which will not be shown to you
> again so we have to note it down.

And when I used this password I am able to git push origin.